# Rotate, Scale, and Translate Bitmap on Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, matrix

I am attempting to rotate, scale, and translate an image for drawing on a Canvas. However, the order is proving to be troublesome and I am having trouble getting everything to line up correctly.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//matrix.postRotate(90f);
matrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
matrix.postTranslate(screenCoords.x - scaleWidth/2, screenCoords.y
    - scaleHeight/2);

c.drawBitmap(blackJackBM, matrix, this.mPaint);
```

The scaling and translate works correctly in this instance, however un-commenting the rotation code will cause the image to be offset, in this case, to the left of where it should be drawing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

postRotate(float) rotates the matrix from its upper left point. Use postRotate(float, centerX, centerY) instead.